# How to resolve "XamlParseException Occurred" In windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I'm developing windows phone 8 application .

I try to add a common style sheet for my WP 8 App Using [Xaml Styles](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/using-styles-and-resources-to-simplify-your-xaml) .

I try with following steps-:

**Step 1:** Add a new text file and save with extension .xaml   [`Stylessheet.xaml`]

`Stylessheet.xaml` Code for `TextBox` Style

```
 <ResourceDictionary
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
     mc:Ignorable="d">
        <Style x:Name="Textblockstyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
          <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold"></Setter>
        </Style>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

**Stpe2:** In `App.xaml` page I add the `stylessheet.xaml` resource

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Stylessheet.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhoneApp1" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

**Step 3:** `mainpage.xaml` apply syle for `textBlock`

```
 <TextBlock Name="txtblock" Style="{StaticResource Textblockstyle}">Hi this is for sample</TextBlock>
```

After apply this code in design window screen text color is change to red and bold.

But I try to run this code i got error in `App.xaml.cs` page in line  `InitializeComponent()`;

Error is "XamlParseException Occurred"

**A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll**

I try with some stack overflow solution but not work for me. 
Please tell why this error occur and how to solve it.

My File path structure

[image]

App.xaml File Code

```
 <Application
x:Class="PhoneApp1.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">

<!--Application Resources-->
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Stylessheet.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhoneApp1" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>

<Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
    <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
    <shell:PhoneApplicationService
        Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing"
        Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
</Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>

</Application>
```

Problem Occur due to this line

What's problem present in this code

```
  <TextBlock Name="txtblock2" Margin="0,50,0,0">This is second sample</TextBlock>
   <TextBlock Name="txtblock3" Margin="0,100,0,0," Style="{StaticResource Textblockstyle}">Final sample Text</TextBlock>
```

Error occur when Margin="0,100,0,0" is present.

After remove this margin . code run correctly . what's problem with this code .

Comment: Source="/Stylessheet.xaml" is correct file path ??

Comment: But i remove the"/" it show me  An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "Stylessheet.xaml"

Comment: JaiHind Now i add my file structure Image For your reference.

Comment: @Gurunathan I've build a simple example basing on your code and it runs fine. Maybe you have an error somewhere else in App.xaml?

Comment: @Romasz Now i add my app.xaml code

Comment: can you check the inner exception and post that to your question as well?

Comment: @Gurunathan Also try to clean solution and rebuild it. In case you have still problems, try to run [my sample code](http://1drv.ms/1eJdU1I)

Comment: @Default unable to understand your question

Comment: @Gurunathan You have additional comma in Margin. `Margin="0,100,0,0,"`

Comment: @romasz Sorry it's mistake . your code work perfectly now my code also work correct

Comment: @Gurunathan I also like such errors - they steal your time and at the end it turns out that it was one char. I'm glad I've helped. Good luck.

Comment: @Gurunathan It the problem is solved, mark an answer as accepted. I think Romasz should add his answer to let you mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little discussion it turned out that the problem was caused by an additional comma in `Margin`:

```
<TextBlock Name="txtblock3" Margin="0,100,0,0," Style="{StaticResource Textblockstyle}">Final sample Text</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your style sheet works perfact, problem is in the line below

```
<TextBlock Name="txtblock3" Margin="0,100,0,0," Style="{StaticResource Textblockstyle}">Final sample Text</TextBlock>*
```

Margin takes an extra comma

```
 <TextBlock Name="txtblock3" Margin="0,100,0,0" Style="{StaticResource Textblockstyle}">Final sample Text</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the forward slash from the Source property in the ResourceDictionary of the MergedDictionary:

...Source=**"Stylessheet.xaml"**...

instead of

...Source=**"/Stylessheet.xaml"**...

Comment: It show me error An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "Stylessheet.xaml"

Comment: What's the Build Action of the file set to (right click on the file => properties), and what's the relative location of the file? The build action should be set to "Page"

Comment: Both stylessheet.xaml and mainpage.xaml buid action property is page only

Comment: Then there must be something else going on that you're not showing. This works without problems.